# Check neighbouring numbers in matrix

Tags: c#, matrix

How do I count all neighbouring ones in a 3x3 matrix, which could look like this

```
1  1  1
1  0  0
0  0  0
```

and my desired output would be( in the square brackets are indexes [x,y], I care only about the numbers, indexes are for accuracy)
[0,0] - 2, [1,0]- 3, [2,0]- 1, [0,1]-2, etc... I do not count the middle number in.

I have a large matrix and task is to loop through each number, imagine this matrix and count how many ones are AROUND the number in the middle.
This is my code, but I cant make it work.

Here is my method:

```
public int CheckArea(int cordX, int cordY)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = cordX - 1; i <= cordX + 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = cordY - 1; j <= cordY + 1; j++)
            {
                if (j != cordY && i != cordX && tileField[i, j])
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
       return count;      
    }
```

It shouldnt be an index problem cos I setup the matrix like this:

```
        tileField = new Boolean[width, height];
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                tileField[x, y] = false;
            }
        }
```

but I do not print the first and last column and row so my Print method is:

```
public void Print()
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < this.width-1 ; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 1; y < this.height -1; y++)
            {
                if (!tileField[x, y])
                {
                    Console.Write("0 ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("1 ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Just find one of many minesweeper implementations...

Comment: Where are you calling the method CheckArea?

Comment: You need to be more specific than "I can't make it work". What doesn't work? Looks like it would. If you are checking along your edges then you are going to be searching items in your array that are in the first and last row or first and last column. What's in those items?

Comment: @jdweng I call it inside 2 for loops, which are exactly the same as in Print method, but are obviously in other part of the code.
for (int k = 1; k < width-1; k++) 
            {
                for (int l = 1; l < height-1 ; l++)
                {count = gameBoard.CheckArea(k, l);}}

Comment: @Marc in the first and last row and column are zeros, so that shouldnt be a problem, the problem is the method is returning wrong numbers, well because its written wrong. If I have a 2x2 matrix filled with ones it returns 1,1,1,1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it might seem like this begs for using loops to reduce code, you might want to just manually check each neighbor as there are only 8 possibilities. The solution below assumes that you aren't interested in "wrapping" around the grid and that there aren't any additional rows/columns in the field other than the coordinates you want to check (like a buffer row and column for top and left edge). I'd suggest doing the following:

```
public int CheckArea(int cordX, int cordY)
{
    int count = 0;
    int fieldWidth = tileField.GetLength(1);
    int fieldHeight = tileField.GetLength(0);

    // Check for the neighbor to the North
    if(cordY != 0)
    {
        count += GetValueAtCoordinate(cordX,cordY - 1);
    }
    // Check for the neighbor to the East
    if (cordX < fieldWidth - 1)
    {
        count += GetValueAtCoordinate(cordX + 1, cordY);

        // NE neighbor
        if(cordY != 0)
        {
            count += GetValueAtCoordinate(cordX - 1, cordY - 1);
        }

        // SE neighbor
        if(cordY != fieldWidth - 1)
        {
            count += GetValueAtCoordinate(cordX - 1, cordY + 1);
        }
    }
    // Check for the neighbor to the South
    if (cordY < fieldHeight - 1)
    {
        count += GetValueAtCoordinate(cordX, cordY + 1);
    }
    // Check for the neighbor to the West
    if (cordX != 0)
    {
        count += GetValueAtCoordinate(cordX - 1, cordY);

        // NW neighbor
        if(cordY != 0)
        {
            count += GetValueAtCoordinate(cordX - 1, cordY - 1);
        }

        // SW neighbor
        if(cordY != fieldHeight - 1)
        {
            count += GetValueAtCoordinate(cordX - 1, cordY + 1);
        }
    }

    return count;
}

public int GetValueAtCoordinate(int x, int y)
{
    return tileField[x,y] == true ? 1 : 0;
}
```

You could use a variety of other methods but unless there is a specific reason you don't want to use the simple path of checking each neighbor I don't think you really save any time with loops. I also added a method which will convert the bool value at a given coordinate to an int of 1 for true and 0 for false as it appears your matrix is of type bools.

**Edit**
If you are treating this as a 1-index array, simply change the edge checks that use the fieldWidth and fieldHeight variables to not reduce by 1.

Comment: My first idea was to do something similar to this, but then I decided to go with loops instead, guess I have a really poor judgment. Thanks a lot, Im gonna try this one out.

Comment: There isn't really a "right" way to do it. If this was more complicated than just checking the eight neighbors it would probably be worth trying to find a more concise solution like Roberto's below.

Answer (score 1):

```
//dx and dy contains a vector of all possible moves: E, NE, N, NW, W, SW, S, SE.
static int [] dx = {1, 1, 0,-1,-1,-1,  0,  1};
static int [] dy = {0, 1, 1, 1, 0,-1, -1, -1};


public int CheckArea(int cordX, int cordY) //i assumed that cordX and cordY was a row and a column of the matrix
{

    int count = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k < dx.length; k++){
        int i = dx[k] + cordX;
        int j = dy[k] + cordY;
        if(canCount(i,j, matrix) && matrix[i][j] == 1){
           count++; 
        }
    }



    return count;      
}
//To check that you are within the bounds of the matrix
public boolean canCount(int i, int j, int [][] matrix){
    return i >= 0 && i < matrix.length && j >= 0 && j < matrix[0].length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, appreciate your answer, but Im gonna stick with exceptionthrown's one. Still thank you for another possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following method return a 2D array which represents the ones count in it.
Note that in this array null for the elements mean current element is not one.

```
private int?[,] matrixOnesCount(int[,] matrixInput)
{
    int?[,] matrixOutput = new int?[matrixInput.GetLength(0), matrixInput.GetLength(1)];

    int rMax = matrixInput.GetLength(0);
    int cMax = matrixInput.GetLength(1);

    for (int r = 0; r < rMax; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < cMax; c++)
        {
            if (matrixInput[r, c] != 1)
            {
                matrixOutput[r, c] = null;
            }
            else
            {
                int numOfOneInNeighbors = 0;

                numOfOneInNeighbors += (r - 1 >= 0) ? matrixInput[r - 1, c] : 0;                        // Top neighborhood
                numOfOneInNeighbors += (r - 1 >= 0 && c - 1 >= 0) ? matrixInput[r - 1, c - 1] : 0;      // Top-Left neighborhood
                numOfOneInNeighbors += (c - 1 >= 0) ? matrixInput[r, c - 1] : 0;                        // Left neighborhood
                numOfOneInNeighbors += (r + 1 < rMax && c - 1 >= 0) ? matrixInput[r + 1, c - 1] : 0;    // Buttom-Left neighborhood
                numOfOneInNeighbors += (r + 1 < rMax) ? matrixInput[r + 1, c] : 0;                      // Buttom neighborhood
                numOfOneInNeighbors += (r + 1 < rMax && c + 1 < cMax) ? matrixInput[r + 1, c + 1] : 0;  // Buttom-Right neighborhood
                numOfOneInNeighbors += (c + 1 < cMax) ? matrixInput[r, c + 1] : 0;                      // Right neighborhood
                numOfOneInNeighbors += (r - 1 >= 0 && c + 1 < cMax) ? matrixInput[r - 1, c + 1] : 0;      // Top-Right neighborhood

                matrixOutput[r, c] = numOfOneInNeighbors;
            }
        }

    return matrixOutput;
}
```

```
int[,] matrixInput = { { 1, 0, 1 },
                        { 1, 0, 1 },
                        { 1, 1, 0 },
                        { 0, 1, 0 } };

int?[,] matrixOutput = matrixOnesCount(matrixInput);
```

The result(`matrixOutput`) is:

```
 1  , null,   1
 3  , null,   2
 3  ,  4  , null
null,  2  , null
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just check that i and j fall within the matrix in CheckArea like this:

```
public int CheckArea(int cordX, int cordY)
{
    int count = 0, matrixLenght = 3;//works for any matrix as long as you change the lenght
    for (int i = cordX - 1; i <= cordX + 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = cordY - 1; j <= cordY + 1; j++)
        {
            (i >= 0 && i < matrixLenght  && j >= 0 && j < matrixLenght  && (i != x || j != y))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
   return count;      
}
```